# Black borders after installing Calalyst 14.4

Tags: catalyst

Have just done a hardware upgrade with existing Ubuntu 14.04, including an AMD APU A10-7700K. But I found that the 3 offerings in Additional Drivers didn't work properly so I couldn't start the Control Centre, and couldn’t get OpenCL.
So I installed the Catalyst 14.4 package from AMD (which wasn't too hard!), but now I get a black border on my screen. My monitor is a Samsung 22" LED S22D300. Otherwise all seems OK. I found some instructions at wiki.cchtml.com but didn't work. Playing with the settings in Control Centre didn't work either.
Anyone else have this problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

See para 5.2. In a terminal:

sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0

sudo reboot

Now have nice full screen!